# How to make new domain redirect to specific page of main domain without losing SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects, nginx

So I have a exchange office (lets say www.example.com) Wordpress website and I bought a new domain just to sell Euro (www.euroexample.com). I want this new domain to show the specific page for Euro exchange in the main domain. What is the best way to do this without affecting SEO? It is now working with a proxypass on Nginx. When I access the euroexample.com, it shows the content of www.example.com/euro. Is this a good idea? It doesn't sound like one.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name euroexample.com www.euroexample.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/euro;
        proxy_set_header Host euroexample.com;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it does not sound like a good idea to you, how would you think I user will find it?